# Does a select SQL Statement on oracle lock the used table for update by other connections?

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, jta

Does a select SQL Statement on oracle lock the used table for update by other connections? is it depend if I'm doing the select inside a jta transaction or not ? how can I control this issue and prevent from read only SQL Statements to lock tables for editing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on a lot of stuff - like your [transaction isolation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10743/consist.htm) setting for instance. Even in auto-commit mode you'd have *some* if rather short transactions on your db.

So yes, a SELECT **can** create a lock that others have to wait for.

If you want to prevent this from happening in large scale and know what you're doing, transaction isolation "read uncommitted" will create fewest locks (and offer least protection)

Comment: so if i set on my jboss data source <transaction-isolation> TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED I can prevent it ? what would be the risk ?

Comment: Read the article i linked. The main risks are dirty or phantom reads - you read data that might not get committed. So it highly depends on what you need that read for.

Comment: mistake - Transaction_read_committed : Guarantees that the data you are getting has been committed. but does it prevent table lock ?

Comment: any way I see that Read committed is oracle default . so will it help ?

Comment: Read committed sounds like "dont change while I read" to me - so locks might occur.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but I think it deserves a better answer. If you reference [Automatic Locks in DML Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/ap_locks001.htm), you will find that the only **SELECT** statements that will lock tables are those with the **FOR UPDATE** clause, and since "queries without the **FOR UPDATE** clause do not acquire any data locks to block other operations, such queries are often referred to as nonblocking queries".